# Как работают условные операторы для дат в MS SQL Server и какой следует использовать?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Делаю выборки данных за 2020 год тремя разными способами:

1. `year(CreationDate) = '2020'`
2. `CreationDate > '12-31-2019' AND CreationDate < '01-01-2021'`
3. `CreationDate BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '12-31-2020'`

Каждый раз я получаю разные результаты. Почему так происходит и какой способ следует использовать?

`CreationDate` имеет тип `datetime`. Под разными результатами я имею в виду количество записей получаемых при `Count(*)`.

Comment: Очередной вопрос от админа

Comment: CreationDate это колонка Date или DateTime или вообще другого типа?

Comment: Как понять "_разные результаты_"?

Comment: Думаю Count(*) различный

Comment: https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разбирать

1. `year(CreationDate) = '2020'` - весь 2020 с [01-01-2020 00:00:00.000 до 12-31-2020 23:59:59.999] **тут без проблем весь 2020**
2. `CreationDate > '12-31-2019' AND CreationDate < '01-01-2021'` - с [12-31-2019 00:00:00.001 до 12-31-2020 23:59:59.999] - **тут весь 2020 + лишний период 12-31-2019 00:00:00.001**
3. `CreationDate BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '12-31-2020'` - с [01-01-2020 00:00:00.000 до 12-31-2020 00:00:00.000] - **тут весь 2020 -и не хватающий почти день период 12-31-2019 00:00:00.001**

Как видно из интервалов это не совсем 2020 год в некоторых случаях. Более подробно с примерами [тут](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2209321/Working-with-SQL-Server-DateTime-Variables-Part-Three---Searching-for-Particular-Date-Values-and-Ranges.htm)

Проблема во времени которые путают все карты. Для получения верного результата нужно обе части сравнения приводить к Date

1. `year(CreationDate) = '2020'` - тут нет проблем
2. Нужно `Cast(CreationDate As Date) > '12-31-2019' AND Cast(CreationDate As Date) < '01-01-2021'` - преобразовать явно к Date
3. `Cast(CreationDate As Date) BETWEEN '01-01-2020' AND '12-31-2020'` - преобразовать явно к Date

Comment: Наиболее разумный подход - это `CreationDate > ='01-01-2020' AND CreationDate < '01-01-2021'`. Он гарантированно может использовать индекс по полю, буде таковой имеется, посему, наверное, будет побыстрее прочих, если сервер не проявит ну очень интеллект...

Comment: Отличное объяснение. Спасибо!